# Why Node.js (filename) causing problems in Node.JS on Windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

I am running Node.JS v12.13.1 on latest Windows 10 build.

I create file named "Node.js" and everytime I call command `node <anything>` in folder with this file, my NotePad++ gets opened with file "Node.js". For every other files or folders, `node` command works fine.

Is filename "Node.js" reserved or I have somehow badly configured system?

EDIT: Not problem with NotePad++ program, even after I uninstalled it I am getting popup to select with what program I want to open this file

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question, but just to mention that this behavior doesn't happen on Linux. Seems to be a Windows-related issue...

Comment: Not tested, but I am sure it is just Windows problem, because Linux does not treat unknown commands as "edit file named <command>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Windows has been configured to treat files ending in *.js as editable rather than executable. See [Change File Associations in Windows](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-file-associations-windows) to tell Windows what to do with such files.

Comment: Not helped. I just want to run `node` command instead of opening `node.js` file :D

Comment: Well, I don't know how to help further since the problem, as you describe it, is certainly caused by incorrect file associations. Try setting the file association for `*.js` to invoke your `node` command (using its full path) and you will be able to run your script. One thing to note though, it's not a great idea to name your scripts with names of runnable commands, as you have in this instance, for just the issue you've encountered.